# Calculate the fundamental group of $S^1 \cup [0,1]$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

> Calculate the fundamental group of $S^1 \cup (\Bbb{R}_{\geq 0}\times\{0\})$

Ok, so Im starting to get the intuition in how to solve this kind of problems, but whenever I try to do it somehow more formally, I get stuck.

So I started by defromation retracting $S^1 \cup (\Bbb{R}_{\geq 0}\times\{0\})$ to $S^1 \cup [0,1]$. And my intuition says that the latter is homotopically equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^1$. By somehow identifying $S^1$ with $I/0\sim1$. The problem is im nowhere close to writing this.

I thought of something like: $f:S^1 \cup [0,1] \to S^1 \vee S^1$

$$f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    x       & \quad \text{if } x \in S^1 \\
    e^{2\pi i t}  & \quad \text{if } t \in [0,1]
  \end{cases}$$

Which is continuous by the pasting lemma, and that it's constant in the classes of the relation $0 \sim 1$. However, I don't know how to say that they go to the different $S^1$ of the wedge. Is this the way? Is there another way?

Comment: What is $S^1$ (in terms of coordinates)?  With the usual definition $S^1=\big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,x^2+y^2=1\big\}$, it looks like $S^1\cup \big(\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\times\{0\}\big)$ retracts to $S^1$, not $S^1\vee S^1$.

Comment: How many points of intersection do you think $S^1$ and $[0,\infty)\times\{0\}$ have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good picture is worth a thousand words.  Presuming that $S^1$ is the usual unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then the set you are describing is pictured below:

[image]

The horizontal ray (i.e. the set $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \times \{0\}$) retracts to a point (in particular, to the point $(1,0)$), and you are left with the circle.